# How can I get command line arguments passed to the running process?

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell, unix

In the Linux platform, if I write in console `ps -p "pid" -o command` I get full line with all argument which passed in terminal when I run the program. Output in console something like this: `COMMAND gedit /home/sasha/Work/unloker/main.cpp  (Ubuntu)`. Now I'm writing the program which main purpose to get complete input command line of process. My C++ code is:

```
snprintf(path_cmdline, sizeof(path_cmdline), "/proc/%d/cmdline", pid);
fd_cmdline = open(path_cmdline, O_RDONLY);
if (fd_cmdline < 0) {
} else {
  char process_name[PATH_MAX];
  if (read(fd_cmdline, process_name, PATH_MAX) < 0) {
  } else {
     pid_info pid_t;
     pid_t.pid=pid;
     strcpy(pid_t.command_line,process_name);
     strcpy(pid_t.process_name,basename(process_name));
     std::cout << pid_t << std::endl;
  }
}
```

and output of my program somthing like this: `10753 gedit gedit`, but how can I get full command line as when the output of the `ps -p "pid" -o command`?

Where in the `/proc/%d/` kept full command line of the running program? In Solaris system I know exist command `pargs` which do what I want, may be how now where I may found sources of this command?

Comment: I just tried it and `/proc/%d/cmdline` had exactly the same information as `ps -p "pid" -o command`.

Comment: consider using /proc/self/cmdline, that way the current process id will not be requried

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The arguments in /proc/pid/cmdline is a list of strings, separated with 0 bytes. Therefore treating it as C string, which is terminated by first 0 byte, will only give you the process name. Replace all 0 bytes up to the size returned by `read` with spaces and try again.

Here is proof:

```
$ hexdump -bc < /proc/32096/cmdline
0000000 142 141 163 150 000 055 162 143 146 151 154 145 000 056 142 141
0000000   b   a   s   h  \0   -   r   c   f   i   l   e  \0   .   b   a
0000010 163 150 162 143 000
0000010   s   h   r   c  \0
0000015
```

Comment: It is answer to the question. The question **already included reading `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`.**

Comment: LoL, sorry, I didn't read his code i skipped to his question at the bottom.

Comment: Jan Hudec thanx,it is what i looking.

Answer (score 1):

in linux, the running process info is stored in the /proc/ folder -
/proc/{PROCESS_ID}/cmdline to be exact - for example here is chrome-

```
 $cat /proc/3193/cmdline 
 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --lang=en-US --force-fieldtrials=ConnCountImpact/conn_count_6/ConnnectBackupJobs/ConnectBackupJobsEnabled/DnsImpact/default_enabled_prefetch/GlobalSdch/global_enable_sdch/IdleSktToImpact/idle_timeout_10/OmniboxDisallowInlineHQP/Standard/OmniboxSearchSuggest/6/Prerender/ContentPrefetchPrerender1/ProxyConnectionImpact/proxy_connections_32/SBInterstitial/V2/SpdyImpact/spdy3/UMA-Dynamic-Binary-Uniformity-Trial/default/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-1-Percent/group_31/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-10-Percent/group_05/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-20-Percent/default/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-5-Percent/group_13/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-50-Percent/group_01/WarmSocketImpact/warmest_socket/ --enable-crash-reporter=81A0480CAE65B69A53CE6E791EAA05A5,Ubuntu 10.10 --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --renderer-print-preview --disable-accelerated-2d-canvas --channel=2980.13.513987986
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant _terminal_. Is that exact copy&paste of your terminal? Because I am almost certain (but can't verify, because I am sitting in front of Windows box right now) that the arguments are separated with NUL bytes. Which would be copied by `cat`, but would be ignored by the terminal, so the arguments wouldn't be separated by spaces...

Comment: RobertMaysJr How can i get this line in c or c++ code?If i read /proc/3193/cmdline a get only process name.

Comment: here's the source code to cat -http://www.c.happycodings.com/C_on_Unix/code7.html, like @jan Hudec said, you might need to replace the 0x00 byte with a space (0x20) - otherwise most C++ string functions will treat it as the end of the string.  (The end of a variable length string is marked with that 0x00 null character - that's how it knows the variable is over.)

Comment: @TopilskiAlexandr: In fact C**++** functions won't; `std::string` will happily include 0 bytes and forward them to streams and such. But C functions won't and any C++ functions that use `char *` for backward compatibility won't either, of course.